# Slider Revolution in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, slider, fadeout

I want to make a slider like a demo: https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/

I can do the parallax option but I need the effect of the content of the demo. 
When scroll I need to fade out the content in Slider Revolution.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to write custom Javascript that will hit the elements within RevSlider. I can tell you right now, this is going to be a huge pain, as the classes and id's on the layers are going to be dynamic and change all the time. Here's some untested jQuery I am throwing together to get you started.

```
// Listen to the scroll event on the window element

$(window).scroll(function() {

  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100 ) {

    // Find the class and fade it out
    // You might need to grab the ID for the layer

    $('.rev_layer_class').fadeOut();

  } else {

    // Fade back in if they scroll back up

    $('.rev_layer_class').fadeOut();
  }

});
```